# Запуск второй формы из первой при нажатии кнопки(С#, UWP, XAML)

Tags: c#, uwp

Проблема заключаеться в том что мне нужно чтобы при нажатии кнопки открывалась вторая форма.

AddInfo - вторая форма. Addinfobutton - кнопка на первой форме MainPage.
Прошу помочь мне с этим обработчиком события нажатия кнопки.

Comment: В UWP разве есть формы?

Answer (score 1):

Ну тут же ничего сложного, в интернете тем более куча информации.

`AddInfo wndw = new AddInfo();
wndw.Show();`

Comment: или ShowDialog(), если нужно модальное окно

Comment: К UWP это точно применимо?

Comment: @Андрей, конечно применимо.